# devise does not pick up namespaced model in rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rails-engines

i want to extract my admin interface in an seperate rails engine. 
Adding devise support for the admin user does not quite work for me. Here is the engine code:

admin user model:

```
AppEditorial::Admin
```

engine routes:

```
  devise_for :admins, :controllers => {
    sessions: "app_editorial/devise/sessions",
    registrations: "app_editorial/devise/registrations",
    confirmations: "app_editorial/devise/confirmations",
    class_name: "AppEditorial::Admin",
    module: :devise
  }
```

That throws an error:

```
/../inflector/methods.rb:229:in `block in constantize': uninitialized constant Admin (NameError)
```

Which makes sense, since the model is namespaced as *AppEditorial::Admin*. adding the *class_name* options doe not work either.

as a starting point i found this tutorial: [Use-devise-inside-a-mountable-engine](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-devise-inside-a-mountable-engine).

the documentation for [devise_for](http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper#devise_for-instance_method).

Answer (score 4):

hoppla. obvious error:

it should be:

```
  devise_for :admins, {
    controllers: {
      sessions: "app_editorial/devise/sessions",
      registrations: "app_editorial/devise/registrations",
      confirmations: "app_editorial/devise/confirmations",
    },
    class_name: "AppEditorial::Admin",
    module: :devise
  }
```

lame :)